# getting the value of a div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i wanted to get the value of a hidden div in jquery i.e.

```
<div id="text">hello i am the value, you want</div>
```

and i want insert this value into a another div in jquery i.e.

```
$('#bio').html($value);
```

EDIT:

i forgot to mention that it had to be the text within the block div sorry i.e. its parent

```
<div class="block" id="status_13">
<div id="text">.......</div>
</div>
```

i.e.

```
$('.block').click(function(){
 $('#bio').html($('$text').html());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `#text` element contains HTML you might want to do:

```
$('#bio').html($('#text').html());
```

If you are only concerned with the literal text of `#text` then  you can do:

```
$('#bio').text($('#text').text());
```

Of course, if you want to store the text in a variable first, you can do so:

```
var textValue = $('#text').text();
$('#bio').text(textValue);
```

In regard to your later edit:

```
$('.block').bind('click', function() {
  var thisTextValue = $(this).children('.text').first().html();
  $('#bio').html(thisTextValue);
});
```

Notice that I assumed the child `div` is marked with a class and not an id. Based on your description, it sounds like you have multiple "block" elements which each contain a "text" element. If that is the case, then `$('#text')` will always return the first "text" element in the document; **IDs are unique in the document**.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use $ for variables (like $value), just `value`

```
var value = $('#text').html();
```

Comment: how can i change it to acess as the child of block div, sorry, there is an updated question :))

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
$('#bio').html($('#text').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work

```
//get the value from hidden field and store it in the variable 'valueYouWant'
var valueYouWant = $("#text").html();

//set it in other field
$("#bio").html(valueYouWant);
```

edit:
More information can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/)